# Rails 4: Knowing bundler from inside out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am working on a **Rails 4** Application, where i localized all the gems to: **vendor/gems** folder.

```
PATH_TO_APP$ bundle install --path=vendor/gems
```

After doing this, I have a folder named: **.bundle** inside my app, which has **config** file in it.

```
# Content inside config file
---
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/gems
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

Later, I realized that, I don't want to **localize** every gem from **Gemfile**. I want my app to use few of the gems from system (**which, can be defined**) and few gems from **vendor/gems** folder.

To accomplish this:

1. I removed **.bundle** folder
2. Removed **Gemfile.lock**
3. Opened **Gemfile** and did the below modification and ran **bundle install**:

   ```
   # source 'https://rubygems.org'
   gem 'rails', '4.1.8', path: "vendor/gems"
   gem 'mysql2', '0.3.17' # I want this gem to load from system instead of defined path
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0', path: "vendor/gems"
   ```

I got this:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Installing mysql2 0.3.17
Using rails 4.1.8 from source at vendor/gems
Using uglifier 2.5.3 from source at vendor/gems
Using bundler 1.6.5
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

When I looked at the **Gemfile.lock**, I saw this:

```
PATH
  remote: vendor/gems
  specs:
    uglifier (2.5.3)

PATH
  remote: vendor/gems
  specs:
    rails (4.1.8)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    mysql2 (0.3.17)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  mysql2 (= 0.3.17)
  rails (= 4.1.8)!
  uglifier (= 2.5.3)!

{PATH_TO_APP} $bundle show mysql2
-> /home/pp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/mysql2-0.3.17
```

I noticed that **rails (= 4.1.8)** & **uglifier (= 2.5.3)** were not able to find the appropriate path.

To change this, I opened my Gemfile again and changed the code to below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8', path: "vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1"
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.17' # Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3', path: "vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1" # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
```

and when I tried running **bundle install** again, I found below trace:

```
activerecord at /home/pp/Workspace/MyProject/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1/specifications did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  ["README.rdoc"] are not files
Using activerecord 4.1.8 from source at vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1
Using bundler 1.6.5
Using execjs 2.2.2 from source at vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1
Using hike 1.2.3 from source at vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1
Using multi_json 1.10.1 from source at vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1

mysql2 at /home/pp/Workspace/MyProject/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1/specifications did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
If you need to use this package without installing it from a gem repository, please contact seniorlopez@gmail.com and ask them to modify their .gemspec so it can work with `gem build`.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  ["ext/mysql2/extconf.rb"] are not files
Using mysql2 0.3.17 from source at vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1
```

And trace from **Gemfile.lock**

```
PATH
  remote: vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.8)
      actionpack (= 4.1.8)
      actionview (= 4.1.8)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.8)
      actionview (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.8)
      activemodel (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.8)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    mysql2 (0.3.17)
    ....

PATH
  remote: vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1
  specs:
    rails (4.1.8)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.8)
      actionpack (= 4.1.8)
      actionview (= 4.1.8)
      activemodel (= 4.1.8)
      activerecord (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.8)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    ....

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  mysql2 (= 0.3.17)
  rails (= 4.1.8)!
  uglifier (= 2.5.3)!
```

**3 things happened here:**

1. Dependencies still doesn't meet.
2. mysql2, instead of picking it from system, bundler is taking it from vendor/gems
3. Warning messages for activerecord and other gems

I am stuck and wondering, what is the best way to accomplish this behavior. Am I missing something or am i following the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

why you localize all your gem in vendor folder ? I would recommended create your own [GemServer](http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/). and change the source path in Gem file, I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Lareb for the solution. However, due to some limitations I cannot opt for having my own **GemServer**. 1st: Since, **GemServer** requires its own port (E.g. localhost:9292). Even if we manage to run this on desired port, later, hosting team (internal) can block this port. I've seen similar kind of issues here.

Comment: 2nd limitation: There are **gems** which are common to all the applications (like **mysql2** etc.) which has be on a shared path (accessible to all applications) for that I may have to define various **sources** inside my **Gemfile**. I know this is not a big challenge and solution to this can be figured out. But now that you have seen this, what is your opinion?